# config.cache_classes = true in production mode has problems in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, production-environment, internet-explorer-8

In my rails app. I am using link_to_function to bring an ajax tabs in one page.Everything works fine in Moazilla and other browsers. But in IE the tabs are not loading only when the server is started in production mode(doesn't matter whether it's webrick or mongrel). In development mode everything is fine. So I figured out that the issue was with one line

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

in app/config/environments/production.rb

when I changed the above code to

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

everything works fine.
So I assume caching causes problem in Rails.
When I Googled about this I found many have the issues with caching.
So my question is

1) is there any other fix for this?

2) Does this fix (`config.cache_classes = false`) causes any performance issues. If then how to overcome that?

Any comments and suggestions are welcome.

Techno_log

Answer (score 3):

cache_classes is setting that tells web server if it should reload whole app for each request.  More precisely:

"Whether or not classes should be cached (set to false if you want application classes to be reloaded on each request)"

(from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Configuration.html)

Setting cache_classes to false will have big impact on your app performance.

However, your problem, most likely, is not related to this setting. I suggest that you take look at IE cache (i.e. try clearing out cache), maybe some caching headers you are setting when generating page, etc.

Also the fact that all other browsers get good response from server means that web server is generating good response.